# Is it true that interest rates options with different maturities are free of calendar arbitrage because of the different underlying rates dynamics?

Tags: options, interest-rates, stochastic-processes, arbitrage

The title says it all - is it true that European style interest rates options (lets say on LIBOR 3M for the sake of simplicity) with different maturities are free of calendar arbitrage because underlying rates are driven by stochastic processes with different dynamics? Can anyone give a more formal statement and a proof or at least a qualitative explanation of this phenomenon?